# Android -Type Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are \b \t \n \f \r \" \' \\ )

Tags: android, string, class, android-manifest

I'm Trying to use a String to change a TextView in an XLM and I keep getting this error. I wont to have each line on a new row. Can anybody help thanks

```
String ingredients = "40ml vodka \n\ 120ml tomato juice \n\ 5ml lemon or lime juice \n\ 5ml worcestershire sauce \n\ 2 dashes tabasco \n\ salt";
```

Throws error

```
Type Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )
```

Comment: 40ml vodka \n 120ml tomato juice , do like this, remove black slash after \n  \

Answer (score 2):

Why are you escaping the spaces? Should work if you leave this out simlly replace every '\ ' with a plain space.

Answer (score 0):

Escape characters are preceded by double backslashes. For example, a newline character is created using ‘\\n’